# Help all my variables are black

Tags: formatting

Some time I ago I changed my format settings and somehow (I can't remember) everything in Mathematica is now black. I'd like my variables to be nicely coloured again. How do I undo this?

It looks like this.

[image]

Comment: Are you using the `Default` Stylesheet for the notebook in question? If not can you try switching to it (using the menu item `Format->Stylesheet->Default`). I know that one can change this coloring with changes to the Stylesheet I am not sure if there is another way to do so...

Comment: Maybe need to reset your settings in  $UserBaseDirectory

(* may be  C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica”  in Windows
 and “/home/YourUserName/.Mathematica” in Linux *)

Comment: My stylesheet is at default. How do I reset my setting my settings once I'm in $UserBaseDirectory?

Comment: @AccidentalTaylorExpansion You just delete everything there except for the License directory (if you do delete that, you'll need to reactivate Mathematica).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so apparently this is really easy. Go to `Edit > Preferences > Appearance` and then inside `Syntax Coloring` press `Reset to Defaults`. I still don't know why/how I changed it but after a year I finally have normal colors again!

[image]